# Mongodb Aggregate events between two events

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection made like this

```json
[
  {timestamp: xxx, type:'start'},
  {timestamp: xxx, type:'log'},
  {timestamp: xxx, type:'log'},
  {timestamp: xxx, type:'log'},
  {timestamp: xxx, type:'start'},
  {timestamp: xxx, type:'log'},
  {timestamp: xxx, type:'log'}
]
```

how do I aggregate the start event and the log event until but not including the next start?

the result should be something like this
something like this

```json
{
  events:[
   {timestamp: xxx, type:'start'},
   {timestamp: xxx, type:'log'},
   {timestamp: xxx, type:'log'},
   {timestamp: xxx, type:'log'}
  ]
},
{
  events:[
   {timestamp: xxx, type:'start'},
   {timestamp: xxx, type:'log'},
   {timestamp: xxx, type:'log'}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you include the documents which is yet to be redacted? Currently, it is ambiguous about what is the expected behaviour.

Comment: And depending on what you're doing and how these logs are generated, it's possible for two groups of of start-log-log-(end) `events` to overlap. So even a solution to this would not actually work. Are you sure that events will only be generated for one event at a time? Is there an `eventID`? If the timestamps are always increasing, then add that to your sample data instead of `xxx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: the timestamp field is "sortable" type

You can use `$setWindowFields` to compute "grouping" for the events. The idea is to find the max timestamp with `start` in the window range of `[unbounded, current]` (i.e. find in the documents before and in current document with a `$max`). After computing the "grouping", just do a simple `$group` to put the events together in an array.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "sortBy": {
        "timestamp": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "grouping": {
          "$max": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$type",
                  "start"
                ]
              },
              "then": "$timestamp",
              "else": -1
            }
          },
          "window": {
            "documents": [
              "unbounded",
              "current"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$grouping",
      events: {
        $push: {
          timestamp: "$timestamp",
          type: "$type"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fZMO9GZmd1e)

P.S. Your expected result form may suffer from [MongoDB 16MB document size](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit) if a single grouping contains too many records.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit difficult, because the way you retracted your data makes your question pointless.

I guess, `timestamp` is a sequence of events. In this case a solution could be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: null, events: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
   {
      $project: {
         events: {
            $reduce: {
               input: { $sortArray: { input: "$events", sortBy: { timestamp: 1 } } },
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $concatArrays: ["$$value",
                     [{
                        $mergeObjects: ["$$this", {
                           branch: {
                              $cond: {
                                 if: { $eq: ["$$this.type", 'start'] },
                                 then: { $ifNull: [{ $add: [{ $last: "$$value.branch" }, 1] }, 0] },
                                 else: { $last: "$$value.branch" }
                              }
                           }
                        }]
                     }]
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$events" },
   { $group: { _id: "$events.branch", events: { $push: { timestamp: "$events.timestamp", type: "$events.type" } } } },
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/53-ZmG0iP9G)

Another solution is this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: { timestamp: 1 },
      output: {
        index: { $documentNumber: {} }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      events: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      starts: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$events",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.type", "start" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      events: {
        $map: {
          input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$starts" } ] },
          as: "i",
          in: {
            $slice: [
              "$events", {
              $subtract: [
                  { $arrayElemAt: [ "$starts.index", "$$i" ] }, 1 ] },
                  { $subtract: [
                  { $arrayElemAt: [ { $concatArrays: [ 
                      "$starts.index",
                      [ { $add: [ { $size: "$events" }, 1 ] } ] 
                      ] },
                      { $add: [ "$$i", 1 ] }
                    ]
                  },
                  { $arrayElemAt: [ "$starts.index", "$$i" ] }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wQOnZ0ZcOyh)

Comment:  Also, in the first solution, you may need to add a sort before the final group by, or at the very start, to ensure that the log groups in the result match their `branch` order. [Minor modification added here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pNzlOqT2QC0).